# Hexagon Grid Algorithm Fail

Tags: javascript, html

I create a game which has as foreground a hexagon grid. I created an algorithm to display the code, but I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at hexagonPosition.js:34.

```js
//hexagonPosition.js

var hexGrid = document.getElementById("hex-grid");

for (var rows = 0; rows < 20; rows++) {
    var hexGroup = document.createElement("div");
    hexGroup.id = ("hex-group" + rows);
    for (var cols = 0; cols < 55; cols++) {
        var hexTile = document.createElement("div");
        hexTile.id = ("hex-tile-x" + cols + "-y" + rows);
        hexTile.setAttribute("class", "hex-tile" + rows);
        hexGroup.appendChild(hexTile);
    }
        hexGrid.appendChild(hexGroup);
}
```

```css
//style.css
.hex {
  clip-path: polygon(75% 10%, 100% 50%, 75% 90%, 25% 90%, 0 50%, 25% 10%);
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
.transparent {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\CSS\style.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="WhatShouldResult">
<div class="hex-grid">
  <div class="hex-group1">
    <div class="hex-tile1">
    </div>
    <div class="hex-tile2">
    </div>
    <div class="hex-tile3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex-group2">
    <div class="hex-tile2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="hex-grid"></div>
  <script src="../JS/hexagonPosition.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post the full JS code as the error appears on line 34.

Comment: between hex-grid line and for line was a posibble commented code:

Comment: Which line is 34?

Comment: hexGrid.appendChild(hexGroup);

Comment: the hexGroup.appendChild(hexTile); does not seem to have a problem from what i see

Comment: That means `hexGrid` is null. Your code looks fine at first glance which makes me think you didn't actually post all of your code or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the following line you are getting the element by ID.

```
var hexGrid = document.getElementById("hex-grid");
```

But in your HTML `hex-grid` is a class, not an ID.

```
<div class="hex-grid">
```

If you change that line of JavaScript to be the following it should work.

```
var hexGrid = document.getElementsByClassName("hex-grid")[0];
```

That will get the first element with the class name of `hex-grid`.

Or of course you could just change the HTML to be an ID instead of a class.